# C# Dynamic array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want an array to contain `strings`, `floats` and `int`s that can be accessed via an index key.

I have an example in Lua how you would do but I don't know how you do it in C#

```
bookArray = [];
bookArray[1] = 
{
    Name = "Book 1";
    Price = 50;
    WPP = 374;
    Pages = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a `class` and use `List<MyClass>`

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public int Pages {get;set;}
}
```

Here is the list:

```
List<MyClass> values = new List<MyClass>();
```

Adding item

```
values.Add(new MyClass(){Name = "Book 1", Pages = 42, Price=50.0});
```

Insert at specific index:

```
values.Insert(0,new MyClass(){Name = "Book 2", Pages = 432, Price=10.0});
```

Retrieve at specific index:

```
MyClass theClass = values[1];
```

Comment: In addition to @Hossein s answer... When using arrays in C#, there's a catch, you need to know the size of the array when you're first instantiating it. So if it's going to be 10 items, you would need to use `Foo[] foo = new Foo[10]`. This is why you're better off using `List<Foo>` as you don't need to worry about that sort of thing

Comment: ...or if it is an index key (non-sequential), then Dictionary<int, MyClass> would be a good choice as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with your inner type being immutable, you could do this:

```
var ar = new[] {
                new { Name = "Book 1", Price = 50, WPP = 374, Pages = 42 },
                new { Name = "Book 2", Price = 55, WPP = 220, Pages = 129 }
            };
```

Which is about as close as you can come to the Lua definition